# Why in a graded ring $A$ finitely generated that's an algebra over a field $K$ every maximal ideal is a $K$-subspace?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, graded-rings, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Probably this question has already been asked, but I'm very bad in find old question and I searched for half an hour, so I'm asking it again.

I suppose that's true beacuse my professor used this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any algebra $A$ over $K$, an $A$-module $M$ is a $K$-vector space by restriction of scalars, and an ideal of $A$ is an $A$-submodule of $A$. This has nothing to do with grading of $A$ nor finitely generated nor maximal ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is more general: Every algebra is a $K$-vector space and every subalgebra is a $K$-subspace. In particular, every ideal.

Comment: Ideals are not subalgebras, but the idea is still valid...

Comment: @darijgrinberg Please could you explain your comment? see e.g. [here](http://planetmath.org/idealofanalgebra) where it mentions that an ideal is indeed a subalgebra.

Comment: Ideals usually don't contain 1, while the standard definition of an algebra involves containing 1. (PlanetMath explicitly claims to use the standard definition, which makes its statement wrong.)